# Fatal Error in mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to learn how to do a prepared statement using some example code below.

I have an initial SQL statement, and for each record returned by that, do another SQL check against the results returned.

```
<?php

$sql_b = "SELECT fld_title, fld_tag FROM j_oracle_cat WHERE fld_tag IS NOT NULL ORDER BY fld_title";

if (!$result_b = $conn -> query($sql_b)) {

    die('There was an error running the query [' . $conn -> error . ']');

} else {

    if (!$result_b -> num_rows) {

        echo "<h4>No Categories Defined</h4>";

    } else {

        while($row_b = $result_b -> fetch_assoc()) {

            $cat_ttl = $row_b["fld_title"];
            $cat_tag = $row_b["fld_tag"];

            echo "<h4><a href='category.php?tag=" . $cat_tag . "'>" . $cat_ttl . "</a></h4>";

            $sql_c = "SELECT p.fld_tag FROM j_oracle_cat c, j_oracle_pages p WHERE c.fld_id = p.fld_catid AND c.fld_tag = ?";

            /* Prepare statement */
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql_c);
            if($stmt === false) {
                trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql_c . '<hr />Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
            }

            /* Bind parameters. Types: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob */
            $stmt->bind_param('s',$cat_tag);

            /* Execute statement */
            $stmt->execute();                       

        }

        $result_b -> free();

    }

}

?>
```

When I run the code, it gets this far:

```
<h4><a href='category.php?tag=accounts-payable'>Accounts Payable</a></h4>
<h4><a href='category.php?tag=accounts-receivable'>Accounts Receivable</a></h4>
```

But then errors with:

> **Fatal error**: Wrong SQL: SELECT p.fld_is_parent FROM j_oracle_cat c, j_oracle_pages p WHERE c.fld_id = p.fld_catid AND c.fld_tag = ?
>   Error: in **C:\xampp\htdocs\php\a.php** on line **95**

Line 95 is this one:

```
trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql_c . '<hr />Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `j_oracle_cat` (
  `fld_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fld_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fld_desc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fld_tag` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fld_label` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fld_parent` int(2) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`fld_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `j_oracle_pages` (
  `fld_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fld_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fld_catid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fld_cols` int(2) DEFAULT '1',
  `fld_left` text,
  `fld_content` text,
  `fld_tag` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fld_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `fld_is_parent` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fld_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=83 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I have tried running the sql direct and it does not error, for a sample tag and it returns e.g. 3 rows:

```
SELECT p.fld_tag FROM j_oracle_cat c, j_oracle_pages p WHERE c.fld_id = p.fld_catid AND c.fld_tag = 'accounts-receivable';
```

Connection to db:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "mydb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if($conn -> connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $conn->connect_error . ']');
}

?>
```

Presumably I am doing something silly, but I can't see what?

Comment: Are you sure that your connection to the database was written correctly?

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you posted your table structure and the actual error message from MySQL, not just "Error: in somefile on line something." What happens if you run this SQL directly with an appropriate value for the parameter?

Comment: Sorry - I have updated the question showing the table structures. If I run the SQL direct in e.g. SQLyog, it does not error and returns 3 rows for the tag of "accounts-receivable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here are my recommendations; I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code, but these steps should make it easier to diagnose the problem, if not fix it outright. First, move the `prepare()` call out of the loop*. Next, [explicitly create the statement object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.stmt-init.php), so that if there's a problem with preparation you can get the error directly from the statement object. Finally, check for a valid return during every stage of the process, including [parameter binding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.bind-param-returnvalues) and [statement execution](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.execute-returnvalues).

```
$sql_b = "SELECT fld_title, fld_tag FROM j_oracle_cat WHERE fld_tag IS NOT NULL ORDER BY fld_title";
if (!$result_b = $conn->query($sql_b)) {
    trigger_error("Error executing query: $conn->error<br/>SQL query: $sql_b", E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
    if (!$result_b->num_rows) {
        echo "<h4>No Categories Defined</h4>";
    } else {
        /* Prepare statement */
        $sql_c = "SELECT p.fld_tag FROM j_oracle_cat c, j_oracle_pages p WHERE c.fld_id = p.fld_catid AND c.fld_tag = ?";    
        $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
        if (!$stmt) {
            trigger_error("Error creating statement: $conn->error", E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        $result = $stmt->prepare($sql_c);
        if(!$result) {
            trigger_error("Error preparing statement: $stmt->error<br/>SQL query: $sql_c", E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        /* Bind parameters. Types: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob */
        // needs a dummy value for the initial bind
        $row_b = array("fld_tag"=>"");
        $result = $stmt->bind_param("s", $row_b["fld_tag"]);
        if(!$result) {
            trigger_error("Error binding parameter: $stmt->error<br/>", E_USER_ERROR);
        }

        while($row_b = $result_b -> fetch_assoc()) {
            $cat_ttl = htmlspecialchars($row_b["fld_title"]);
            $cat_tag = htmlspecialchars($row_b["fld_tag"]);
            echo "<h4><a href='category.php?tag=$cat_tag'>$cat_ttl</a></h4>";
            /* Execute statement */
            $result = $stmt->execute();
            if(!$result) {
                trigger_error("Error executing statement: $stmt->error<br/>Bound parameter value: $row_b[fld_tag]", E_USER_ERROR);
            }
            // I assume you'll be doing something with $result down here?
        }
        $result_b->free();
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

Couple of side notes: You should always escape database results with [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) before putting them into HTML, to avoid risk of injections. You can [use double quotes to include variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) inside strings, and avoid having dozens of unnecessary `.` operators everywhere. This is a matter of personal preference, but many find it more readable.

*One of the big benefits of prepared statements is that they [separate the preparation of the query from its execution](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), avoiding the overhead involved in setting up MySQL to run the query. By repeatedly preparing a statement, you remove that benefit entirely.